# Using DOMDocument to Parse HTML with JS code

Tags: php, html-parsing

I take HTML in as a string and then I parse it to change all href links to something else. This works however, when the HTML page has some JS script tags i.e. `<script>` it gets removed! For example this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Gets Changed to:

```
[removed][removed]
```

However, I would like to keep everything in. This is my function:

```
function parse_html_code($code, $code_id){

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = new DOMDocument();

$xml->loadHTML($code); 

foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {

  $link->setAttribute('href', CLK_BASE."clk.php?i=$code_id&j=" . $link->getAttribute('href'));

}

return $xml->saveHTML();

}
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: DOM will not remove any tags on it's own or insert `[removed]` markers anywhere. Please provide a reproducable example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: X-Ref: [PHP Headless Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578132/php-headless-browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter's bogus anti-XSS ‘feature’ is mauling your script's input before DOMDocument gets a look at it. Script tags and various other strings will be removed, replaced with “[removed]” other otherwise messed-about with for no good reason. See the system/libraries/Security.php module for the full embarrassing details.

To turn off this misguided feature, set `$config['global_xss_filtering']= FALSE`. You'll have to make sure your script is actually handling string escaping properly, of course (eg always HTML-escaping user input when including in a page). But then you have to do that anyway; anti-XSS doesn't fix your text processing problems, it just obscures them.

```
$link->setAttribute('href', CLK_BASE."clk.php?i=$code_id&j=" . $link->getAttribute('href'));
```

You'll need to `urlencode` that `getAttribute('href')` (and potentially $code_id if it's not just numeric or something).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and tip about the URL encode! I feel like I have to defend CI since I am using it, but I am not going to as I don't much about it...yet, but I am sure it has its pros.