# What's the best way to do headless browser testing with PHP in Linux (specifically Ubuntu)?

Tags: php, automated-tests, headless

I would like to write some automated UI tests for a PHP web app, and was wondering what the best way to do it on Ubuntu would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://seleniumhq.org/  http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/

Comment: thank you, this looks exactly like what i'm looking for :-) chris