# Download html after javascript loads with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having a trouble with my script. It is supposed to download html from another website and use some specific data and output it to my website. But the website I need to download the html from uses javascript to generate some important data. How can I download the html after javascript has loaded, and use ajax to sent it to php?

Before I was using the `file_get_contents`, but that only downloads the raw html.

Comment: Get the HTML via PHP and then parse it with it, do the animation with jQuery afterward, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I am totally lost, I haven't no idle how I can do it. I am just asking what would be the best way to handle this.

Comment: You have to think on how to execute your own js code from the web-target domain. I mean, you need to use something like `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, which gives you the ability to execute javascript. So, you have to load the page, then execute the same JS than the web executes by ajax by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to a headless browser, i only know https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs PhantomJs, but i'm sure there are others.

Comment: Is not possible to do this without using PhantomJs

Comment: you can look to this thread there is others solutions :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578132/php-headless-browser. But it's better to use well done libraries instead of recreating the wheel.